# Simple Deferred / Promise pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've wrote a very simple implementation of Deferred / Promise pattern (inspired by jQuery's `$.deferred`) for my tiny project (which does not use jQuery)

It can handle multiply `onSuccess` an `onFail` callbacks with result caching. Example in comments above the code.

```
/**
 * defer() returns methods:
 *      resolve(data) - request is successfully resolved (returns nothing)
 *      reject(msg) - request if failed (returns nothing)
 *      promise() - returns promise function
 *
 * promise() returns methods:
 *      done(successfulCallback) - add on successful callback (returns nothing)
 *      fail(failCallback) - add on fail callback (returns nothing)
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * function someHeavyRequest(url) {
 *      var d = defer();
 *      doHeavyRequest(url,
 *          function (data) {
 *              // on success
 *              // ...do something
 *              d.resolve(data);
 *          },
 *          function (data) {
 *              // on fail
 *              // ...do something
 *              d.reject(data);
 *          });
 *      return d.promise();
 * }
 *
 * var req = someHeavyRequest("http://some.url/of/request/");
 *
 * req.done(function (data) {
 *      console.log("We got it!");
 *      console.log(data);
 * });
 *
 * req.done(function (data) {
 *      console.log("We got it again without new request!");
 *      console.log(data);
 * });
 *
 * req.fail(function (data) {
 *      console.error("Something wrong");
 *      console.error(data);
 * });
 *
 */
function defer () {
    var status = 0, // 0 = in progress / 1 = successful / -1 = fail
        callbacks = { done: [], fail: [] },
        args = { resolve: [], reject: [] },
        execute = function (callbacks, args) {
            var f;
            while (callbacks.length) {
                f = callbacks.shift();
                if (f) f.apply(this, args);
            }
        };

    return {
        promise: function () {
            return {
                done: function (callback) {
                    callbacks.done.push(callback);
                    if (status === 1) {
                        execute(callbacks.done, args.resolve);
                    }
                },

                fail: function (callback) {
                    callbacks.fail.push(callback);
                    if (status === -1) {
                        execute(callbacks.fail,args.reject);
                    }
                }
            };
        },

        resolve: function () {
            status = 1;
            args.resolve = arguments;
            execute(callbacks.done, args.resolve);
        },

        reject: function () {
            status = -1;
            args.reject = arguments;
            execute(callbacks.fail, args.reject);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: These things are not "thenable" and they don't integrate with other "thenable" things, so I don't think it's accurate to call them promises. Looks interesting, though. Will do a proper review after I get some sleep if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: Since you're inspired by jQuery's deferred objects, why not implement the `always` callback as well?

Comment: Adding `always` is good idea. I've missed this because `always` call not required in my project at now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things caught my eye:

- You can call `resolve` *and* later call `reject` too - or the other way around, or call either one multiple times. It should only allow the first resolve/reject call to have an effect.
- `status` might as well be a string (`pending`, `resolved`, `rejected`) which obviate the need for a comment explaining the integer values, and would improve readability
- The `if(f)` check in `execute` should probably be a full `if(typeof f === 'function')` check; lots of values are truthy without being *functions*. You could also do this check in `done`/`fail` and simply ignore/complain about non-function arguments.
- There's some duplication between `done`/`fail` and `resolve`/`reject`.

For that last one, if the status becomes a string, it's also relative easy use that as a key for organizing the callbacks and arguments.

```
function defer() {
  var currentState = 'pending',
      callbacks    = { resolved: [], rejected: [] },
      args         = []; // only need 1 args array

  function execute(state) {
    var cb;
    while(callbacks[state].length) {
      cb = callbacks[state].shift();
      if( typeof cb === 'function' ) cb.apply(this, args);
    }
  }

  // generic function factory for done/fail functions
  function hook(state) {
    return function (cb) {
      callbacks[state].push(cb);
      if(currentState === state) execute(state);
    }
  }

  // generic function factory for resolve/reject functions
  function complete(state) {
    return function () {
      if(currentState !== 'pending') return; 
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
      currentState = state;
      execute(state);
    }
  }

  return {
    promise: function () {
      return { done: hook('resolved'), fail: hook('rejected') };
    },
    resolve: complete('resolved'),
    reject:  complete('rejected')
  };
}
```

You may want to add `then`, `always` and `isPending` (or just `state`) functions. And once you've resolved or rejected, you might as well get rid of the callbacks you're not going to ever use (i.e. if resolved, clear out the reject-callbacks,and vice-versa).

Lastly, if you want to emulate jQuery, make it chainable, so you can call `x.done(...).fail(...).fail(...).always(...)` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments (especially about if check). Now the code looks much cleaner!

Comment: @ofstudio No problem. And (looking at the commments above), it'd be nice to add `always` and possibly `then` - and it should be pretty straightforward too. By the way, I'll just simplify my code slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `always` handler. Now the code looks like this (thanx to Flambino)

```
function defer() {
    var currentState = 'pending',
        callbacks    = { resolved: [], rejected: [], always: [] },
        args         = []; //

    function execute(state) {
        var cb;
        while(callbacks[state].length) {
            cb = callbacks[state].shift();
            if( typeof cb === 'function' ) cb.apply(this, args);
        }
    }

    // generic function factory for done/fail functions
    function handle(state) {
        return function (cb) {
            callbacks[state].push(cb);
            if(currentState !== 'pending') {
                if(currentState === state) execute(state);
                if(state === 'always') execute('always');
            }
        }
    }

    // generic function factory for resolve/reject functions
    function complete(state) {
        return function () {
            if(currentState !== 'pending') return;
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
            currentState = state;
            execute(state);
            execute('always');
        }
    }

    return {
        promise: function () {
            return {
                done: handle('resolved'),
                fail: handle('rejected'),
                always: handle('always')
            };
        },
        resolve: complete('resolved'),
        reject:  complete('rejected')
    };
}
```

Very useful thing (missed in initial version):
`args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);`
This line of code [magically converts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work) `arguments` from object into array

Comment: There is no reason to convert the arguments list to an array, since it is never exposed and is only passed as an argument to `apply`, which will happily take either an array or an instance of `Arguments`.